# HTML menu hovers content instead of pushing it down

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a fixed nav bar menu and on a mobile device it's automatically a hamburger menu courtesy of bootstrap 4.

There is one little issue I have. When I open the hamburger menu, it hoves over the content below, I don't want it to hover over the content, but instead push the content below down when the menu is open.

Remember this is a fixed navbar, so it's currently doing the default behaviour of hovering over the content below when open. I want the navbar to remain fixed, but I want it to open an close like.a sticky menu.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/../#"><img src="../img/logo.png" alt="Metis Skills and Careers Logo"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#top">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#about">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#courses">COURSES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#services">SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/../#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a>
              </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#contact">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

visit website https://www.metis-online.com on mobile device and open the menu and you can see what I mean when it hovers over the content below

Comment: you are need `position: sticky`?

Comment: So on the desktop website, I need to the navbar to remain fixed. On the mobile I need it to also be fixed but when open, it pushes down content just like how a static top opens a hamburger menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think it only makes sense to push the content down when the user is at the top of the page (ie scroll position is 0).

So the trick is, in mobile view, for the `nav` block to change to `position:fixed` as soon as the user starts scrolling.

I've created [this example](https://codepen.io/clayrav/pen/oNbOyzz) by forking and modifying a CodePen by Chris Coyer, from [this article](https://css-tricks.com/styling-based-on-scroll-position/).

He uses IntersectionObserver, because event-based scroll testing can lead to all sorts of performance problems.

You'll need to get rid of your `.fixed-top` class and add the following CSS (it can probably be improved to make it more DRY)...

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  body.nav-not-at-top {
    padding-top: 80px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 80px;
  }
  nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}

body.nav-not-at-top nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  width: 100%;
}

#top-of-site-pixel-anchor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  left: 0;
}
```

At the start of your page content (ie after your nav header) add the following HTML...

```
<div id="top-of-site-pixel-anchor"></div>
```

This is what's used to check the scroll position.

Then add the following Javascript, probably just before the `</body>` closing tag...

```
if (
  "IntersectionObserver" in window &&
  "IntersectionObserverEntry" in window &&
  "intersectionRatio" in window.IntersectionObserverEntry.prototype
) {
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  if (entries[0].boundingClientRect.y < 0) {
    document.body.classList.add("nav-not-at-top");
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove("nav-not-at-top");
  }
});
observer.observe(document.querySelector("#top-of-site-pixel-anchor"));
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This looks awesome. I will give it a try later. Thank you very much :)